# ShellWindows and OutOfMemoryException?

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, out-of-memory

I have a method to open an URL in Internet Explorer. If there already is an internet explorer open, it should open in a new tab. If there isn't it should open a new internet explorer.

**My code:**

```
    public static void OpenURL(string Url)
    {
        bool already_navigated = false;

        ShellWindows instances = new ShellWindows();

        //Check if there is an Internet Explorer
        if (instances.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (InternetExplorer ie in instances)
            {
                if (ie.Name == "Windows Internet Explorer")
                {
                    if (!already_navigated)
                    {
                        //Navigate and open in New Tab
                        already_navigated = true;
                        ie.Navigate(Url, 0x10000);

                        //Bring window to front
                        IntPtr hwnd = (IntPtr)ie.HWND;
                        WindowHandler.Window w = new WindowHandler.Window(hwnd, "Internet Explorer");
                        w.Minimize();
                        w.Restore();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        //No internet explorer found!
        if (!already_navigated)
        {
            //Start new Internet Explorer
            Process proc = Process.Start("IExplore.exe", Url);
        }
    }
```

This works great! But when I call this code my memory increases in an infinite loop untill I get an **OutOfMemoryException**...

After some trial and error I found that **this code throws an exception:**

```
    public static void OpenURL(string Url)
    {
        bool already_navigated = false;

        ShellWindows instances = new ShellWindows();
        /*
        //Check if there is an Internet Explorer
        if (instances.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (InternetExplorer ie in instances)
            {
                if (ie.Name == "Windows Internet Explorer")
                {
                    if (!already_navigated)
                    {
                        //Navigate and open in New Tab
                        already_navigated = true;
                        ie.Navigate(Url, 0x10000);

                        //Bring window to front
                        IntPtr hwnd = (IntPtr)ie.HWND;
                        WindowHandler.Window w = new WindowHandler.Window(hwnd, "Internet Explorer");
                        w.Minimize();
                        w.Restore();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        //No internet explorer found!
        if (!already_navigated)
        {
            //Start new Internet Explorer
            Process proc = Process.Start("IExplore.exe", Url);
        }*/
    }
```

And this code **doesn't:**

```
    public static void OpenURL(string Url)
    {
        bool already_navigated = false;
        /*
        ShellWindows instances = new ShellWindows();

        //Check if there is an Internet Explorer
        if (instances.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (InternetExplorer ie in instances)
            {
                if (ie.Name == "Windows Internet Explorer")
                {
                    if (!already_navigated)
                    {
                        //Navigate and open in New Tab
                        already_navigated = true;
                        ie.Navigate(Url, 0x10000);

                        //Bring window to front
                        IntPtr hwnd = (IntPtr)ie.HWND;
                        WindowHandler.Window w = new WindowHandler.Window(hwnd, "Internet Explorer");
                        w.Minimize();
                        w.Restore();
                    }
                }
            }
        }*/
        //No internet explorer found!
        if (!already_navigated)
        {
            //Start new Internet Explorer
            Process proc = Process.Start("IExplore.exe", Url);
        }
    }
```

Which leaves me only one conclusion, the problem lies with:

```
 ShellWindows instances = new ShellWindows();
```

But after some googling, I couldn't find anyone with a similar problem. So I am not sure if I am doing something wrong, or if I am even right about the problem.

Does anyone knows what is going on?

Comment: I bet is a memory leak. Sounds weird in C# but yes, there can be
Why dont you break it at differrent point and see which like is increasing the use of memory??
[Memory Leak is possible](http://crazorsharp.blogspot.com/2009/03/net-memory-leaks-it-is-possible.html)

Comment: @AnnArbor87 I can't really debug because on the moment I can't test the code on the machine I use to develop. I can only debug by changing my code and obeserving what happens.

Comment: Try to comment out other part of the code, like the inner IF (!already_navigated) and post what happens

Comment: And I think the problem you have is because the IE object.
Do you close the instaces?
What do you want to achieve?

Comment: That didn't make a difference. Only whenever I remove the ShellWindows line, it doesn't give a memory leak.

Comment: How many instances do you have ??? 'InternetExplorer ie in instances'

Comment: @AnnArbor87, that depends on the amount of Explorers I currently have open. But I doubt that the memory usage of that list is the problem. Mainly because the leak is gradual and I can call the method multiple times before it finally fails.

Comment: Thats because u dont close it.
[Check here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752084(v=vs.85).aspx)
ie.Quit();

Comment: @AnnArbor87, I tried adding
try{ie.Quit();}
catch(System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException) { ;}

It didn't help.

Comment: And didnt work?
Then your problem is the pointer 100% sure

Comment: @Jordy - Why exactly can't you debug your code? Which exception does the single line of `... new ShellWindows()` throw exactly. It would be interesting to know what the value of `iCount = ShellWindows.Count` is exactly.

Comment: But he says he cant debug it, however he can put a counter and print it, no?

Comment: @Ramhound the problem is my PC I use to developt doesn't have an internet connection, my workstation does have internet but doesn't allow any downloads, so I have to build my code, put it on a flash drive and then run on my workstation.

When I dry run this code on my PC, it doesn't give a leak. So I guess the internet connection has something to do with it?

Comment: @Jordy - So change the code to open a blank page in IE, you still have IE installed, not having an internet connection isn't a reason you can't debug the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ShellWindows is a COM object.  You rely on the garbage collector to get the RCWs (Runtime Callable Wrappers) released, taken care of by their finalizer.

But this won't work so well when your code only ever calls OpenUrl() but doesn't do much of anything else.  The garbage collector only runs when you allocate managed objects.  If you don't do this, and your code as posted doesn't do much of that, you'll run a significant risk of running out of *unmanaged* memory, the kind used by COM objects.

The condition is easy to diagnose, use Perfmon.exe and look at the performance counters for .NET CLR Memory.  The "Gen 0 Collections" counter shows you how often a gen 0 garbage collection is performed.  If that counter doesn't change often enough while your code runs then an OOM kaboom is likely.

This is why GC.Collect() exists, count off the number of "ie" instances you create and call Collect at some kind of magic number.  Marshal.ReleaseComObject() can help too, usually more trouble then it's worth but should operate without trouble here.  And do use *break* in your loop.

Another aspect of ShellWindows is that it is an apartment threaded COM object.  An expensive word that means that it is not thread-safe.  That matters in COM, it takes care of thread-safety on behalf of the object.  You'll can well get into trouble if this code doesn't run on the main thread of a Winforms or WPF app.  Like a console mode app or a service.  Or if you run this code on a worker thread.

That's not a happy home for an apartment threaded COM object, it requires an STA thread to get the thread-safety requirement fulfilled.  COM will take care of that, it will create a *new* thread to give the object a safe home.  This can get out of hand when you create a lot of objects that live too long.  Easy to diagnose as well, turn on unmanaged debugging and keep an eye on the Debug + Windows + Threads window.  We don't know what the rest of your code is doing, but seeing hundreds of threads there when the code has been running for a while spells doom.  Each thread gobbles a megabyte of virtual memory for its stack, it doesn't take more than a couple of thousand to exhaust a 32-bit process.  Fix that by applying the [STAThread] attribute on your Main() method or by calling SetApartmentState() on a Thread before you start it.

Comment: Thank you, I got it working! What I did is create a new Thread in OpenURL, start it and join it in STA. This seems to handle everything nicely!

Answer (score 1):

This code should work with you:

```
public static void OpenURL(string Url)
{
    var t = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Shell.Application");
    dynamic o = Activator.CreateInstance(t);
    try
    {
        var instances = o.Windows();

        // Check if there is an Internet Explorer
        if (instances.Count > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < instances.Count; i++)
            {
                var ie = instances.Item(i);
                if (ie == null) continue;

                var path = System.IO.Path.GetFileName((string)ie.FullName);
                if (path.ToLower() == "iexplore.exe")
                {
                    //Navigate and open in New Tab
                    ie.Navigate(Url, 0x10000);
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(o);
    }

    //No internet explorer found. Start a new onr
    Process.Start("IExplore.exe", Url);
}
```

Comment: When I tried to implent your code I got two errors. The first one states that in order tu use "using" ShellWindows must be convertable to System.IDisposable. Second error is that I can't apply indexing with[] to an expression of ShellWindows.

Comment: I am curious how and how many times OpenURL() is called within the duration of each run of your application? Is your application a Console app, Windows (UI desktop) or what?

Comment: Try remove the first using, keep the foreach, but apply the rest of recommendation

Comment: Please try the code I just added. It worked on my machine as you expected.

Comment: I only call it once before it starts to go cookoo bananas. I only work with .NET 4.0 but I found your answer very informative.

Comment: I actually tried the code I posted above and it works perfectly as you would expect. If it works for you, please don't forget to mark it as the Answer for your question. Thanks.

Comment: I am unable to test it because Marshall is .Net 4.5, and currently I am limited to 4.0